# About a counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $(X,\mathcal S ) $ is a measurable space and $f:X \to [-\infty ,\infty] $ is a function such that $f^{-1}((a ,\infty)) \in \mathcal S $ for every $a \in R$ . Then $f \  $  is $\ $ $ \mathcal S $ - measurable . I am trying to disprove this statement by searching counterexample .I am trying to construct a characteristic function for counterexample .Can any one give me some counter example if this statement is false and if true then please give me proof .

Comment: Do the sets $(a, +\infty)$, $a \in \Bbb R$ generate the Borel algebra on $\overline{\Bbb R}$? If so then $f$ is measurable, if not then maybe not.

Comment: So, is it the case that $(a, \infty ] = (a, \infty) \cup \{ \infty \} ?$ If yes, then can I concluded that the open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ generate the extended borel sets in $\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) ?$

Comment: The whole idea here is this: Can I treat $\infty$ as just a symbol and adjoin it to open rays and go ahead or is there any structure related properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\mathcal{B}=\{A \subseteq \overline{\Bbb R}=[-\infty,+\infty]\mid f^{-1}[A] \in \mathcal{S}\}$. It's easy to check that $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\overline{\Bbb R}$ and it contains all of $\mathcal{B}':=\{(a+\infty)\mid a \in \Bbb R\}$. If $\mathcal{B}'$ generates $\text{Bor}(\overline{\Bbb R})$ then $f$ will be measurable by definition, as then $\text{Bor}(\overline{\Bbb R}) \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ from the given  $\mathcal{B'}\subseteq \mathcal{B}$ inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Take Borel sigma algebra for simplicity.
Define $f(x) = +\infty$ if $x \in V$ (V for Vitali or any non-measurable set you like) and $f(x) = -\infty$ otherwise.
Then $f^{−1}((a,∞)) = \emptyset$ for all $a$, but $f$ is not measurable.